# vba value property from function that returns range

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to build a class in Excel VBA. One of my private fields is (supposed to be) set using a call to a function that returns a range, and then directly assigning the .Value property of that function return.

Here's the basic gist of my code:

```
' Somewhere up in the private field declaration
Dim mMill as String

' Where the private field is set (internal to class)
mMill = getMill().Value

' The 'getMill() function
Private Function getMill() As Range
' Define the range of the mill

Set getMill = mLandingSheet.Range("D1")

End Function
```

I'm getting an error on the 'End Function' line for not having an object variable or with variable set. My thought is that Excel won't allow me to call a function and return the .Value property of the returned object (Range in this case) on the same line. I've verified that I can use the function to return a range and assign to some other variable, and then access the .Value property from there. I'd rather not have to do that, though.

Thanks, y'all!

Comment: I think you need to explain more fully with example code that causes the issue, `getMill` does not interact with `mMill` so its unclear why its there.

Comment: If your saying `Set getMill = mLandingSheet.Range("D1").Value` does not work, it wont because the function must return a `Range`

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for responding. I've included the portion of the code that reflects where the errors are coming from. getMill is the function that is called on the line: mMill = getMill().Value.

Also, the function getMill() returns a Range as it should; I've verified with another variable (Set temp = getMill()). My issue arises when I try to assign the .Value property directly after the function call (which should return a string from what I understand) to the mMill variable (dimmed as a String type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, wow. So...my bad everyone! I lied to myself and to you!

My private field variable (mMill) was NOT set as Private mMill As String like a seemed to indicate in my post. It is actually assigned as Private mMill As Range! Duh! Changing it to Private mMill As String has corrected the problem.

Again, my bad; thank you @Alex for critiquing me enough to get my to overcome my blind spot on this matter.

Sorry for the mixup!

Answer (score 0):

Should the values be set using `Property`?

For example:
Create a class called `clsMillExample`.

Add this code to the class:

```
Private mMill As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MillRange = mLandingSheet.Range("D1")
End Sub

Public Property Get Mill() As String
    Mill = mMill
End Property

Private Property Let MillRange(Reference As Range)
    Select Case Reference.Value
        Case Is <> ""
            mMill = Reference.Value
        Case Else
            mMill = "Empty"
        End Select
End Property
```

Add this code to a normal module:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MillClass As clsMillExample
    Set MillClass = New clsMillExample

    MsgBox MillClass.Mill

End Sub
```

I generally use this site for reference:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx